# New Class doesn't have a setItem Method

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, this is my code.

```
def classMaker(csv):
    csv = csv.split("/n")
    firstLine = csv[0]
    csv = csv[1:]
    class newClass():
        def __init__(self, line):
            self.vars = firstLine
            for i in range(len(line)):
                self[firstLine[i]] = line[i]
    return [newClass(line) for line in csv]
```

The problem is an AttributeError in self[firstLine[i]] = line[i]. It says

`AttributeError: newClass instance has no attribute '__setitem__'`

I don't know why it is causing this error. My goal is to take in a csv file exported from Excel and auto-generate object names from field names.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you intending `self[firstline[i]] = line[i]` to do?  Objects don't support use of the `[]` to assign items unless you define some behavior for that.

Comment: *Aside*: You almost certainly want `"\n"`, not `"/n"` in the 2nd line of code.

Comment: Another aside: Your class should inherit from `object` if you want to use any modern features.

Comment: BrenBarn I want to modify the dictionary directly. Ideally, afterwards, I should be able to say `x = classMaker("someFile.csv")` `x[1].name` and get a sensible answer.

Comment: voithos , thank you for that. The change has been made.

Comment: FYI, if you implement the `__setitem__` method (and `__getitem__`), then you will be able to use subscripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I can infer your intent correctly, you want to replace this line:

```
self[firstLine[i]] = line[i]
```

with this:

```
setattr(self, firstline[i], line[i])
```

This will create an attribute of your `newClass` object named after the column in your data.

E.g.:

```
Name, Date, Weight
Joe, 23-Sep, 99
...
```

and

```
data = classMaker('file.csv')
```

will produce :

```
data[0].Name == 'Joe'
```

P.s. I assume that you will add file I/O, parsing the CSV file, and other missing elements.

P.p.s: You can avoid the loop counter `i` altogether:

```
for attr, val in zip(firstLine, line):
  setattr(self, attr, val)
```

P.p.s: Here is a complete working sample:

```
import csv

def classMaker(filename):
  class newClass(object):
    def __init__(self, line):
      for attr, val in zip(firstLine, line):
        setattr(self, attr, val)
  with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    firstLine = spamreader.next()
    return [newClass(line) for line in spamreader]

x = classMaker("/tmp/x.csv")
print x[0].Name
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, but now I am hitting other errors. Will confirm correct answer as soon as I can check that it does what I want. 

Yes to adding the rest. I cut out everything that was not related to the error for posting here.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the `newClass` all together if you use [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
CSVRow = namedtuple("CSVRow", firstLine)
return [CSVRow(*line) for line in csv]
```

This assumes that the CSV headers will be valid Python identifiers (that is, if you have entires like "Some Value" this won't work if you don't process `firstLine`.

This will let you do things like this:

```
# Let's assume your CSV has a Name field
# and that it is the first column
csv_data[3].Name == csv_data[3][0]
# True
```

Also, you should look into the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to simplify CSV processing.

Comment: At this point using it as a file is rather integrated into a substantial amount of code, and I am not going to change it. But, thank you, this method is the correct tactic and I wish that I had used it.